# API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Access Denied: Project ppc-big-query: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I created a Google Sheet that extracts data from Big Query via a sidebar. I am able to get the data when I run the function via a custom menu or if I execute the function from the Editor. The function simply queries a table in BQ and outputs the data in the sheet.

However, I'm getting an error when I try to run the function via a submit button in the sidebar. I am using google.script.run in the HTML file to execute the Apps Script function. Here's the error that I'm getting:

**Error:
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Access Denied: Project xxx: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project xxx.**

Again, I am able to access BQ from a custom menu or from the Editor which means I have access to BQ, I believe. So I am not sure how to resolve this kind of error. I have been trying to rummage the internet for a solution but to no avail. I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the relevant `google.script.run` code and the server function it calls, together with the code you have that gets the result you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the response @doubleunary

The google.script.run code is simply calling a function that will run the BQ query. Below is the query function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error tells you that you are missing a role that is required by Apps Script.

How to resolve this issue:

You need to tell the administrator to [`Edit your existing role`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#editing_an_existing_custom_role) in Google Cloud IAM and add the `bigquery.jobs.create`. There are other roles that you can add such as `bigquery.jobUser` and `bigquery.user`, these two roles have `bigquery.jobs.create` and other roles.

Why does this happen?

There are different BigQuery roles, maybe you can see the data and you probably have the Bigquery DataViewer role or the BigQuery Editor role, these two roles allow you to read data of your project but they does not have the specific role that Apps Script needs to use.

You can see [here all the BigQuery roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery).

Comment: Thanks for the response!

My account has the BigQuery Job User and BigQuery User roles when I checked. Both has the bigquery.jobs.create permission. That's why I'm not sure why it's throwing the bigquery.jobs.create error.

Comment: I recommend you to  use a [`service account` key stored in the Script propierties](https://www.labnol.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script), which is probably more fitting for a public-facing application. This `service account needs to have the same roles.

Comment: Revisiting the roles solved the issue. The administrator handled it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @viciousJester, can you specify what did you or the administrator do to fix the issue? I am facing the exact problem with my account. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @alson_y! I can no longer remember the exact details but the administrator rechecked the roles and did what Jose suggested above.